# How to call a base class method

Tags: java

How to call a base class method. In the method "test" of the "invoke" class, I'm trying to upcast to the base type to call exactly its method, but for some reason I have an equal call to the derived method

```
class BaseClass {

    protected void print(){
        System.out.println("This is method print from BaseClass");

    }

}

class DerivedClass extends BaseClass{

    @Override
    protected void print() {

        System.out.println("This is method print from DerivedClass");

    }
}

public class invokeDrawing{

    public void test() {

        DerivedClass derived = new DerivedClass();
        derived.print();

        System.out.println("****************");

        BaseClass derivedTest = (BaseClass)derived;
        derivedTest.print();

    }
}
```

Comment: You could add a method on it which would call the superclass method specifically

Comment: You can't. This defeats the whole purpose of overriding the method `print()` in the first place

Comment: What is the purpose of this? Why do you override the method in the first place if you want the super of the method? Why don't you instantiate the superclass if you want the method of the superclass?

Comment: in fact, this is an educational example, and I am experiencing the possibilities of language.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a method on it which would call the superclass method specifically, like this:

```
public void superPrint() {
    super.print();
}
```

And then call it from your derived class:

```
derived.superPrint();
```

Answer (score 0):

Java polymorphism works differently than you expect. When a method of an object is called, the 'most specific' method is invoked, unless specified otherwise. This makes sense, because you always want your object to behave the way the implementation intends, and not the way the base class intends (because the base class does not know the specific class - In other words, you have more context in the derived class, and therefore that behavior is more applicable).

In your example, the object is still of type `DerivedClass` despite you 'casting' it to `BaseClass`. The casting only shrouds the fact that you actually have a `DerivedClass`-Object, but the behavior still comes from the method overriden in `DerivedClass`.

If you want to invoke a super-method from a derived class, you can use the `super` keyword:

```
public String toString() {
    return "123 " + super.toString();
}
```

There are hacks to work around this, if you really, really need it, but usually you don't.